# Fatal error LNK1302: only support linking safe .netmodules; unable to link ijw/native .netmodule

Tags: c++

I have native unmanaged code. I have created a managed C++ DLL and try to include this DLL into native unmanaged code. I got the following error

> fatal error LNK1302: only support linking safe .netmodules; unable to link ijw/native .netmodule

How can I include managed C++/CLR DLL into native unmanaged code?

Comment: I met the same issue, after change the correct .net framework version. It works well now.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the library ('.lib') file and not the DLL ('.dll') as an input to the linker?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are adding the library ('.lib') file and not the DLL ('.dll') as an input to the linker. That will definitely produce a LNK1302 error.

Answer (score 4):

Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x035d1s%28VS.80%29.aspx

"To correct this error, compile with /clr:safe to enable MSIL linking, or pass the /clr or /clr:pure .obj file to the linker instead of the module."

Comment: I just tried this and then I got something like 60,000+ errors instead of just the 1 linker error! Any ideas...?

Comment: I tried to compile with /clr:safe and didn't work. But it worked when link with /clr .obj files.